# Do we say "someone rang the doorbell" for the machine that monitors people entering a building?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I live in an apartment of a building and when my friend visits me, they can not get into the building unless they press my apartment number on a system placed in the front of the building.

There is another piece of equipment with a screen installed in my house.

And when visitors press my apartment number, the equipment will make noise and I will come to look at its screen. If I know the visitors, I will press to unlock the building gate and the visitors can enter the building to go up to my apartment.

**What is that piece of equipment in my house called?**

I can't call it a doorbell because I have a doorbell installed on the door of my apartment, can I?.

In a casual everyday conversation, can I say "**someone rang the doorbell**" when I hear the noise from that equipment?

Comment: I used to say that someone 'buzzed on the door phone' or 'buzzed on the entrance intercom' when I lived somewhere like that.

Comment: It's called a buzzer, not a piece of equipment. ring the buzzer

Comment: I would call it a doorbell.  *Doorbell* doesn't have to literally mean "a bell attached to your door"; anything that serves roughly the same function could be called that.

Comment: @stangdon - I would personally find it a little odd to call something that buzzed a 'doorbell'. I know terms for familiar things can change, but to me bells go 'drrrrring'. Chimes go 'ding-dong'. Things that go 'bzzzzzzz' are buzzers.

Comment: Also with those door intercoms where the person inside can press a button to unlock the street door (and the lock has a buzzer to signal that this is happening), we can say e.g. 'I buzzed her in'.

Comment: If you live in an apartment block, you don't have a "house".  You have a "flat" (British) or "apartment" (American).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In casual speech "rang the doorbell" is fine. But you can call it an "intercom"

> When you get to the building press 5 on the intercom, and I'll buzz you in.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually called a "buzzer".

- Someone rang the buzzer.
- Someone buzzed.

It's not correct to say "someone rang the doorbell" in contexts where one buzzer serves multiple apartments.